# Get index of first detected space after a certain index in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

In a string to format (mostly to replace chars with different symbols for rendering test on UI), I have to detect % and then skip all chars util first space from this % char and it has to be repeated for all instances in the string.

**E.g.** `abcd%1$s efgh %2$d ijkl` .In this string, I have to get index of % and then find index of first space from that. Basically, I have to skip this `%1$s` & `%2$d` which are some sort of formatting placeholders. I hope, I am not putting it in complex way here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get that pretty easily, just grab the index if the first percent sign and then leverage that index to find the first space from there:

```
var start = myString.IndexOf("%");
var spaceIndex = myString.IndexOf(" ", start)
```

of course the value of myString is the string you represented in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following is easiest, and extensible, for your requirement "`abcd%1$s efgh %2$d ijkl` in this string I have to skip this `%1$s` & `%2$d` which are some sort of formatting placeholders."

```
string[] placeHolders = new string[] {"%1$s", "%2$d"};
string[] splits = "abcd%1$s efgh %2$d ijkl".Split(placeHolders, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

which will provide `splits` as `["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"]`